# Defining commutation relations with Flat functions

Tags: function-construction

Here is a minimal example of the problem I am having.

```
f[a___, b_, c_, d___] /; Not@OrderedQ[{b, c}] := h[b,c]f[a, c, b, d]
f[b, a, B, c, A]
SetAttributes[g, Flat]
g[a___, b_, c_, d___] /; Not@OrderedQ[{b, c}] := h[b,c]g[a, c, b, d]
g[b, a, B, c, A]
```

The `f` function works great. The `g` function goes into an infinite loop. How can I work around this problem? Perhaps an alternative to the `Flat` attribute or some other way of defining the commutation relation?

By the way, I set the attribute `Flat` because `G[b, a, B, c, A]` is often built up as follows:

```
SetAttributes[G, Flat]
G[b, G[G[a, B, c], A]]
```

Thanks to @alephalpha for explaining what the problem is and suggesting the following fix. EDIT: <strike>Actually the implementation below still runs an infinite loop on the second test cases below, independent of the order of definitions.</strike> EDIT: found a fix for that loop.

```
(* Flatten g instead of declaring Flat attribute *)
(* The next line was a failed attempt and gets overwritten *)
g[a___, b_g, c___] := Flatten[g[a, b, c]]
(* This line works *)
g[a___, b_g, c___] := Module[{temp},
  temp = Flatten[Hold@g[a, b, c], \[Infinity], g] // Release]
g[a___, b_, c_, d___] /; Not@OrderedQ[{b, c}] := h[b, c] g[a, c, b, d]
g[b, a, B, c, A]
g[b, g[g[a, B, c], A]]
```

I am not sure how this will affect the pattern matching of other definitions, so I will leave the question open to see what others come up with and possibly get a discussion of the pros and cons of `Flat` vs `Flatten`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem of pattern-matching.

When Mathematica evalutes the expression `g[b, a, B, c, A]`, it attempts to apply any transformation rules for `g`. Here the transformation rule is:

```
g[a___, b_, c_, d___] /; Not@OrderedQ[{b, c}] :> h[b, c] g[a, c, b, d]
```

So Mathematica will find out the pattern that match `g[a___, b_, c_, d___] /; Not@OrderedQ[{b, c}]`. But `g` has the attribute `Flat`, so `g[b, a, B, c, A]` is the same as `g[g[b], g[a], B, c, A]`. So the first pattern Mathematica finds to match the pattern is `g[g[b], g[a], B, c, A]`. So it gets:

```
h[g[b], g[a]]g[g[a], g[b], B, c, A]
```

Of course, it is the same as:

```
h[g[b], g[a]] g[a, b, B, c, A]
```

Then Mathematica continues to evaluate `g[a, b, B, c, A]`, which is the same as `g[g[a, b], g[B], c, A]`. `OrderedQ[{g[a, b], g[B]}]` returns `False` because `g[a,b]` has two arguments while `g[B]` has one. So it gets:

```
h[g[b], g[a]] h[g[a, b], g[B]] g[g[B], g[a, b], c, A]
```

which is the same as:

```
h[g[b], g[a]] h[g[a, b], g[B]] g[B, a, b, c, A]
```

Then Mathematica evaluates `g[B, a, b, c, A]` and gets:

```
h[g[b], g[a]] h[g[a, b], g[B]] h[g[a], g[B]] g[a, B, b, c, A]
```

But `g[a, B, b, c, A]` is the same as `g[g[a, B], g[b], c, A]`. So it gets:

```
h[g[b], g[a]] h[g[a, b], g[B]] h[g[a], g[B]] h[g[a, B], g[b]] g[b, a, B, c, A]
```

So it goes into an infinite loop.

---

You can use

```
Flatten[G[b, G[G[a, B, c], A]]] /. G -> f
```

Comment: I am not accustomed to `Flatten` anything other than `List`. Thanks for pointing it out. I updated the question to show my interpretation of your suggestion. Do you see any secondary effects coming from replacing the `Flat` attribute with the `Flatten` function?